# Updating User Information using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Updated code, after information is typed in and the submit button clicked to run this code, it goes back to the account page but doesnt update the database:

```
<font face="ClearSans-Thin">
<font color="lightgray">

<?php

include 'editaccount.php';
include 'connection.php';
?>

<center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['uregsubmit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['ufirstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['ulastname'];
    $email = $_POST['uemail'];
    $dob = $_POST['udob'];
    $user = $_POST['uregisterusername'];

    $pass = $_POST['uregisterpassword'];

    }

    //the query
$query = "UPDATE Users SET FirstName='$firstname', LastName='$lastname' WHERE Username='$user'";
//execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
//check and see if any data returned





?>
</center>
```

Comment: i don't think the comma is supposed to be before `WHERE`

Comment: I didn't have it in before not sure why it's there now. But I removed that and when I click submit it doesn't update the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write sql query inside if statement

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['uregsubmit'])) {
    $firstname = $_POST['ufirstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['ulastname'];
    $email = $_POST['uemail'];
    $dob = $_POST['udob'];
    $user = $_POST['uregisterusername'];
    $pass = $_POST['uregisterpassword'];

    //the query
    $query = "UPDATE Users SET FirstName='$firstname', LastName='$lastname' WHERE Username='$user'";
    //execute the query
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)
    or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($connection));
    //check and see if any data returned
}
?>
```

Comment: inside if statement do `print_r($_POST)` & check whether you get all data or not

Comment: I get this output: Array ( [ufirstname] => test [ulastname] => test [uemail] => [udob] => [uregisterusername] => [uregisterpassword] => [uregsubmit] => Submit )

Comment: So it is storing test and test as the entered fields, it just doesnt change anything in the database

Comment: you don't get username via post method that's your error

Comment: $user = $_POST['uregisterusername']; I do there don't i?

Comment: I'm only testing out changing the first name and last name for now

Comment: but you are using username as reference in where clause to you need value of username

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra comma before WHERE

Comment: Also, the table name in MYSQL is case sensitivity. your table is Users or users?

Comment: It stores what I've entered as test and test: Array ( [ufirstname] => test [ulastname] => test [uemail] => [udob] => [uregisterusername] => [uregisterpassword] => [uregsubmit] => Submit )